# How to include a variable in another variable

Tags: python, arrays

I have a set of variables: `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, `x5`.

```
x1 = 10
x2 = 20
x3 = 30
x4 = 40
x5 = 50
number=1
for looper in range(0,4):
    xnumber = xnumber + 10
    number = number + 1
```

To get: `x1 = 20`, `x2 = 30`, etc.
Because I got:

```
"'xnumber' is not defined"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Use an array instead, defining `x[0] ... x[4]` and replacing `xnumber` with `x[number]`. Also, you can do without defining `number` and use the loop index:

```
x = range(5)
x[0] = 10
x[1] = 2
x[2] = 30
x[3] = 40
x[4] = 50
for i in range(0,5):
    x[i] = x[i] + 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Better use a list for this:

```
x = [10, 2, 30, 40, 50]
for index, value in enumerate(x):
    x[index] = value + 10
```

or a dict, if you want some 'names' for your values:

```
x = {'x1': 10, 'x2': 2, 'x3': 30, 'x4': 40, 'x5': 50}
for key, value in x.items():
    x[key] = value + 10
```

or a class:

```
class x:
    x1 = 10
    x2 = 2
    x3 = 30
    x4 = 40
    x5 = 50

for index in range(1, 6):
    attr_name = 'x%d' % index
    setattr(x, attr_name, getattr(x, attr_name) + 10)
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Additionally, is there any possible way to include one variable into another one? e.g, if x1, and x2, etc, don't have integer values?

Comment: Yes, list and dict values, class attributes can be any object, including lists and dicts: `x = {'first_key': 1, '2': [1,2,[4,5]], 3: {'a': 7}}`

Answer (score 0):

Integers aren't mutable. The only way to get what you want is to reassign each variable to a new integer, and you must do that individually to each variable - there's no way to create a loop to do it.

As an example of what I mean, here's what you could do if the values were mutable. I've changed each variable to contain a list instead of an int.

```
x1=[10]
x2=[20]
x3=[30]
x4=[40]
x5=[50]
vars = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]
for looper in range(0,4):
    vars[looper][0] = vars[looper][0] + 10
print x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
[20] [30] [40] [50] [50]
```

Notice that `looper` only goes up to 3 so it misses `x5`.

Comment: This answer is a correct answer for a completely different question. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro, I don't know what you mean. The question was how to update individual variables from within a loop, and I stand by my answer that you can't without using each variable individually. The other answers that suggest replacing the variables with a list are sidestepping the problem.

Comment: @LennartRegebro, see my edit. It's not the cleanest solution to the question but it proves my answer wasn't off topic.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. It's not a very good answer, though, using a list or a dict just solved the problem, as per the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary.

```
>>> d = {'x1':10,'x2':20,'x3':30,'x4':40,'x5':50}
>>> for key in d:
...   d[key] = d[key] + 10
>>> for key in sorted(d):
...   print key, '=', d[key]
...
x1 = 20
x2 = 30
x3 = 40
x4 = 50
x5 = 60
```